# Communication between Activity and Fragment Using Viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, fragment, communication

Comunication between activity and framgment is not working, observing barcode is executing when ubdating barcode LiveData value.

MainActivity

```
private val viewModel: BarcodeViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        **viewModel.barcode.observe(this) {
            binding.barcodes.text = it
        }**
    }
```

in ScannerFragment i am creating viewmodel like this and updating barcode value when it scanned.

```
private val viewModel: BarcodeViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

BarcodeViewModel

```
class BarcodeViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val mutableSelectedItem = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val barcode: LiveData<String>  = mutableSelectedItem

    fun selectBarcode(item: String) {
        mutableSelectedItem.value = item
    }
}
```

i am trying to create shared instance of BarcodeViewModel. after updating barcode Livedata update UI in MainActivity.

Comment: Did you check if both viewModels have same instance?

Comment: yes, both viewmodel have same instances